# Where is dividend information published?

Tags: stocks, dividends

When a company decides to pay a dividend, where does that information go first?  Lots of site re-publish the dividend but where do they go to find this information quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the stock exchanges where the entity is listed. Under that specific company details, you should be able to find i.e. company filings, details about company reports per quarter, dividends information and much more. Or go to a website like [CNN Money](http://money.cnn.com/) or a financial publication like [Financial Times](http://www.ft.com/home/uk). These are reliable sources more so than individual bloggers and the likes of them.

Other way is to go a company's website and to the investor/shareholder's section where they generally post such information. Company website's aren't updated as fast as the stock exchange websites.

Example

- [Tiffany on
  NYSE](http://secfilings.nyse.com/files.php?symbol=tif)
- [Tiffany on
  CNN Money](http://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=TIF)
- [Tiffany Investor's website](http://investor.tiffany.com/)

Comment: Interesting .. So I guess the dividend would go in as a deposit from the company directly to the NYSE for example.  Then the company would make the filings after the fact.  Companies like CNN and Financial Times would aggregate (or have a 3rd party aggregate) the data from the exchanges.  Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe you are correct. CNN and FT most probably get it from EDGAR(http://www.sec.gov/edgar.shtml). I would assume filings to NYSE and SEC happen at the same time, I am not sure though.